# where is lib folder in bullet physics library

Tags: c++, game-development, bulletphysics

Bullet Physics library

I don't find file of type (.lib) in Bullet Physics library

i don't find lib folder in Bullet Physics library because i want to put the path of the folder in visual studio

Comment: ¿Perhaps you need to build this library first?

Comment: This is probably the simplest way to build that library on msvc: [https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3#build-instructions-for-bullet-using-vcpkg](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3#build-instructions-for-bullet-using-vcpkg)

Comment: ***I don't find file of type (.lib) in Bullet Physics library*** This is normal and expected for many open source libraries on github. You publish the full source code and allow the user to build themselves with whatever compiler (and OS) they choose instead of providing binaries only for windows, macOS and/or a few linux distributions.